# QML: How to disable borders at TreeView and TableView?

Tags: qt, treeview, tableview, qml, borderless

I can remove background of this elements and alternating colors, but I can't find how to remove border around of it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I found solution:

```
TreeView {
    style: TableViewStyle {
        frame: Rectangle {
            border{
                color: "#42414a" // color of the border
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you found the solution, mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 8):

If you only want to remove the border:

`frameVisible: false`